# Mapeamento Entity Framework - DDD

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ddd

Eu estou começando a trabalhar com um projeto DDD.
Acontece que estou tendo muitas dúvidas, e por mais que eu pesquise, cada vez mais fica confuso.

Criei essa `classe`:

```
public class Teste {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
}
```

E essa `interface`

```
public interface ITesteRepository
{
    void Add(Teste queryResult);
    void Update(Teste queryResult);
    void Delete(Teste queryResult);
    IQueryable<Teste> GetByTesteId(int  testeId);
}
```

Sei que preciso criar o mapeamento agora, mas não estou sabendo como começar, já pesquisei na internet, se alguém tiver alguma explicação que me ajude, facilitando o meu entendimento, ou algum exemplo que eu possa seguir.

**Edit**

Seria algo como:

```
public class ClienteConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);

        Property(c => c.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        Property(c => c.Sobrenome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        Property(c => c.Email)
            .IsRequired();

    }
}
```

Porém queria saber como fazer, qual a lógica.

Comment: @Costamilam assisti os dois vídeos, e não consegui tirar a minha dúvida, editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Costamilam ah sim, é pq ainda estou fazendo testes, e tentando entender rs, mas mesmo assim foi de bastante valia os vídeos. Obrigado.

Comment: @Renan Eu criei a `classe` e a `interface` de `repository`, porém essa parte de mapeamento eu tenho dúvidas. Por exemplo. em core, eu crio a model, então adiciono no context, e então dou um `add-migration Model` e então um `update-database` ele cria o mapeamento. Como o projeto é `DDD` não sei como proceder. Estou iniciando agora, por isso ainda estou com bastante dúvidas.

Comment: Está usando o EF ou EF Core?

Comment: Agora `EF`, porém só utilizei em `Core`, igual informei acima. Acho que por isso está me confundindo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que esse exemplo pode lhe auxiliar, Mariana.

```
 public class TestDriveRepository : GenericRepository<TestDrive>, ITestDriveRepository
{
    public TestDriveRepository(DataContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TestDrive> GetByFilter(DateTime? initialOpeningDate = null, DateTime? finalOpeningDate = null, bool onlyEnabled = false, bool onlyExpired = false)
    {
        var query = from td in this.Table.AsNoTracking()
                    join u in base.context.Users on td.UserId equals u.Id
                    where (!onlyEnabled) || (u.Enable)
                    select td;

        if (initialOpeningDate.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(initialOpeningDate.Value));

        if (finalOpeningDate.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.OpeningDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(finalOpeningDate.Value));

        if (onlyExpired)
            query = query.Where(td => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(td.ExpireDate) < DateTime.Now);

        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.OpeningDate);
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ITestDriveRepository
{
    TestDrive GetById(object id);

    void Insert(TestDrive entity);

    void Update(TestDrive entityToUpdate);


    IEnumerable<TestDrive> GetByFilter(DateTime? initialOpeningDate = null, DateTime? finalOpeningDate = null, bool onlyEnabled = false, bool onlyExpired = false);

    TestDrive GetTestDriveById(long userId);

    TestDrive GetHashForValidation(string token);

    TestDrive GetTestDriveByToken(string token);

    DbContextTransaction BeginTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Vinícius, o problema que não sei como fazer isso no meu projeto. Até então eu ja ate baixei alguns projetos com DDD pra me ajudar. Por exemplo o mapping eu consigo gerar automático, ou preciso criá-lo ?

Comment: Eu precisei criar todos. Digo, em projeto real. 
Nesse print, mostra a forma que organizei o projeto em DDD: http://prntscr.com/nfwx3v 
obs: na camada 'Application' está a camada de serviço.